# Children's book about a magic ointment that brings inanimate objects to life

Tags: identification-request

I am trying to find the title of a children's book where a magic ointment was rubbed on inanimate objects (chairs, table etc.) bringing them to life.
I read this book in the mid to late 1970s. Would appreciate it if anyone could identify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That sounds like it could be something by Enid Blyton. In the 1970 compilation book "Happy Time Stories", one story - "The Boy Whose Toys Came Alive!" - features a magical yellow ointment the title character (Sammy) receives as a reward from a brownie for saving his pet rabbit, that will make his toys come to life. He uses it to bring his toys to life, but they have all learnt to be naughty from Sammy's naughty behaviour. They take the ointment and use it to bring all the furniture to life too.

> Goodness, you never heard such a noise as that furniture made! The table at once began to dance round and round, first on one leg and then on the other. The chairs played "Catch" with one another, and banged all round the room trying to grab each other with their legs.

It seems the story was originally published in Enid Blyton's Sunny Stories number 195, in October 1940.

[image]  [image]